# Eliminar caracteres especiales en excel

Tags: excel

Buenas a todos y a todas.

Estoy buscando maneras para poder eliminar caracteres especiales de varias celdas en excel.

Por ejemplo, de la A2:A50 que reemplace los caracteres especiales de las celdas seleccionadas.

Ejemplo:

H&*O^&@LA --> HOLA

La función en un principio, no debería ser ejecutada a través de una macro.

¿Cómo podría entonces reemplazar los caracteres especiales?

Tengo la idea de hacerlo con una macro, por ejemplo usando un bucle con una cadena de caracteres y haciendo un reemplazo en cada celda pero no tengo claro cómo podría hacerlo en la hoja sin una macro.

He probado con : =REPLACE("XYZ123",4,3,"456"), pero replace pide las posiciones que han de ser reemplazadas. En este caso no sabría cuáles son las posiciones a usar.

PD: Usar una extensión no es una solución.

Gracias.

Comment: Aporta el código/lo que hayas intentado para poder tener un punto de partida y así solucionar tu problema más rápido

Comment: Editado, espero haberte ayudado a entender la pregunta.

Comment: Lo que buscas no es el replace, es la funcion sustituir. Para el ejemplo que pones la funcion que necesitas es la siguiente `=SUSTITUIR( SUSTITUIR( SUSTITUIR( SUSTITUIR(B2;"&";"");"*";"");"^";"");"@";"")`. Voy  a relizar una respuesta explicando como tienes que hacerlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me temo que necesitas VBA para resolverlo de una forma fácil. Una macro como tal no, pero puedes crear una UDF que te permita fácilmente limpiar los caracteres que no te interesen.

Yo he diseñado una UDF muy sencilla, totalmente personalizable:

```
Public Function LIMPIAR_TEXTO(ByVal vThisRange As Range)
Dim MiTexto As String
Dim i As Long
MiTexto = vThisRange.Value

'<<<<<LISTA ASCII PERMITIDA >>>>
'48 TO 57 SSon números del 0 al 9
'65 to 90 son letras del alfabeto anglosajón, en mayúsculas, A-Z
'97 to 122 son letras del alfabeto anflosajón, en minúsculas, a-z
'164 to 165 la letra Ñ en mayúscula y minúscula
'32 es el espacio
'<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

For i = 1 To Len(MiTexto)
    Select Case Asc(Mid(MiTexto, i, 1)) 'Sacar código Ascii de cada carácter
        Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122, 164 To 165, 32
            LIMPIAR_TEXTO = LIMPIAR_TEXTO & Mid(MiTexto, i, 1)
        Case Else
            'no hacemos nada, que lo ignore
    End Select
Next i

End Function
```

Esta UDF lo que hace es mirar el código ASCII de cada carácter. Mediante un Select, podemos elegir qué caracteres ASCII permitimos y cuales no. Ahora mismo esta UDF solamente admite números, letras sin tilde, y la letra ñ. Imagina que quieres limpiar el texto que tienes en A1, pues en B1 escribiríamos `=LIMPIAR_TEXTO(A1)`

Varios ejemplos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solamente tienes que modificar la parte que dice `Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122, 164 To 165, 32` con los códigos ASCII de los caracteres que sí quieras permitir. Puedes añadir que permita saltos de línea, comas, paréntesis, letras con tilde, etc.

Adáptalo a tus necesidades.

> Puedes ver todos los caracteres ASCII en https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/

Comment: Muchas gracias.

La función pinta muy bien.

La probaré.

Answer (score 3):

La funcion `Replace` lo que hace si no recuerdo mal es remplazar en X posicion, pero tu lo que buscar es `SUSTITUIR`. Te explico:

A partir de este ejemplo que has puesto :

> H&*O^&@LA --> HOLA

La funcion correcta seria esta  (B2 es mi celda en mi excel):

```
=SUSTITUIR( SUSTITUIR( SUSTITUIR( SUSTITUIR(B2;"&";"");"*";"");"^";"");"@";"")
```

Pero , ¿Como ampliar este ejemplo a cualquier carácter?

- **Un Susituir por cada carácter**: Tienes que crear una función por cada carácter que quieras filtrar en este caso eran 4. Cuando llegas al ultimo Sustituir, creas la funcion original es decir la que busca la ***celda*** `SUSTITUIR(B2;"&";"");`.
- Una vez creada la función principal no hace falta repetir la llamada a la celda ya que como esta anidada todas las demás funciones saben en que celda estas y solo necesitas ir añadiendo los siguientes filtros `"*";"")`; , `"^";"");` y `"@";"")` . Obviamente  si vas a intentar cambiar mas caracteres te espera una larga tarea , puedes crear una lista e ir tomando valores de esta hasta completar tu filtro eso ya queda a tu criterio.